# Почему нет запятой в романе Булгакова?

Tags: запятые

*И, наконец, Воланд  летел тоже  в своем настоящем обличье. Маргарита не могла бы сказать, из чего сделан повод его коня, и думала, что возможно, **что это лунные цепочки(,) и самый конь – только глыба мрака,** и грива этого коня – туча, а шпоры всадника – белые пятна звезд.*

Вопрос с другого форума. Я считаю, что запятая нужна, там был такой же вопрос.
Или не нужна?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152237/discussion-on-question-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

**Из комментариев**

— **Думаю, нужна**. Тем боле перечисление ..,и,и,а

— **А почему не поставили?** Во всех изданиях запятой нет, только в одном нашлась. Отсутствие запятой тоже надо обосновать. Здесь **по семантике** она вроде бы нужна, если правильно понять эту семантику. А ее, вероятно, понимают неправильно. Что такое **лунные цепочки**? По тексту луна всех изменила...

Повод у коня — лунные цепочки, конь — глыба мрака, грива — туча, шпоры — белые пятна звёзд. Лунная дорожка на воде может имеется в виду, но не суть, просто **пересечение частей коня и явлений ночного небосвода**. Абстрактный конь состоящий **из черноты и пятен света.**

**— **Значит, ставим?** А ее точно** во всех изданиях нет? А то у автора спрашивают: Где вы нашли это предложение без запятой?  У меня есть книга 1988 года, там нет запятой.

— Я не знаю) у меня сейчас под рукой книги нет.

— @Sharon, последняя часть, видимо, **не является** соподчиненной.

— **Почему?** Сочинительные союзы: И, А между однородными изъяснительными придаточными. В первом придаточном нет союза, но это **не влиет на постановку запятых**. Обратим внимание, что интонация **перечислительная**, то есть все паузы обозначены.

— Союз и соединяет **два придаточных**. Последняя часть не является соподчиненной.

— Серж, а вы понимаете, что однородность определяется **видом придаточных**. И вот здесь у нас **4 однородных ИЗЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНЫХ** придаточных, причем **как по грамматике, так и по смыслу**. У них общий изъяснительный союз ЧТО. И неважно, какими сочинительными союзами они связаны. Маргарита все это думала и представляла. **Опорное слово: возможно** (что?).